# How to spilled string that contins string in Quote in java

Tags: java, string

I find this function in JAVA to spilled string
I need to make it save the Quote symbol in the output

Like this example:

> hello I am "string type"

the output will be:

> hello
> I
> am
> string type

expected output:

> hello
> I
> am
> "string type"

```
public static String[] split(String str) {
str += " "; // To detect last token when not quoted...
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean inQuote = false;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if (c == '"' || c == ' '|| c=='\n' && !inQuote) {
        if (c == '"')
            inQuote = !inQuote;
        if (!inQuote && sb.length() > 0) {
            strings.add(sb.toString());
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        }
    } else
        sb.append(c);
}
return strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);}
```

any idea to improve this function thank you,

Comment: @AndyTurner What do you mean can you explain more? thanks

Comment: Do you expect strings like `here is "another \"string\""`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew right,